# border radius CSS for this shape

Tags: css, shapes

I want this border shape with pure css for my website pagination
[image: shape I want]

Comment: Hello new dev, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. I don't want to sound harsh, but what have you tried that didn't work? We kind of expect questions to show a similar amount of investment as a good answer would be. So please share your efforts, and we would be happy to improve on them.

Comment: could you please update your post with that info, so it's a bit more legible? You can click [edit] to edit your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't hash it out too much, but I'd do it with before and after pseudoclasses. Create a circle before that matches the color of your link's background color, then create a circle after that matches the color of the page background.

```
div { position: relative; }

a {
    width: 150px; height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:before {
    content: "";
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: -50px;
    border-radius: 9999px;
    z-index: -1;
}

a:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: -50px;
    border-radius: 9999px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/be2ax/